# How can I count the words in DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data that comes from the consumer survey. In the survey, there is the question specifically asking how to improve the service in relation with the service list they want to receive from the delivery service, and the data was stored in open-ended. Since the data is sentence, I ran the text mining, and I got the list of some nouns in column. The data is like as below.

[image]

Thus my question is how to calculate these words. I want to have the frequencies per each word. This might look like this.

Apple 330
Orange 250
Pear 180
...

How can I code to count each words in column list?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `df['Text_mining'].explode().value_counts()`.

Answer (score 0):

`explode` dataframe on the column. Apply `count_values` to the column.

```
df.explode('Text_mining')['Text_mining'].value_counts()
```